# Swift Compiler Shows Expected Declaration Error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app that helps people find bars near them. However, when building my app, an "expected declaration" error appears:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class BarVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var backBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var barMapBtn: UIButton!

    let regionRadius: Double = 1000

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "bars"
    request.region = regionRadius 

    @IBAction func backBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Is this code not where it should be? Do I need to conform to anything? Please help thanks!

Comment: Also, the error appears on the [request.naturalLanguageQuery = "bars"] line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call your code in inside the scope

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "bars"
    request.region = regionRadius

}
```

or you can use as

```
 let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     request.naturalLanguageQuery = "bars"
    request.region = regionRadius

}
```